# Changing the typed character in angular using keypress or keyup event

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an object with a character mapped to another character.

```
 let m = {
    a : 'z',
    b : 'y',
    c : 'x',
    d : 'w',
    ...
    z : 'a'
 }
```

I want an input field in angular 9, such that when user type **a**, then instead of **a**, that character that is mapped to `key a` is typed in the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest you to have a look at keyCodes, instead of using letters as keys, but taking [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/b62u4dk7/)

You can catch the `keydown` event on the input with Angular, then, if the pressed key's `keyCode` is in your map, you can prevent the `keydown` normal behavior, adding your letter instead of the one pressed.

Note that I've chosen `keydown` as it fires before the value gets updated, so if you prevent it, you can manipulate the output. using `keyup` will call your handler **after** the key has been pressed, so you will have both letters in your input

If you don't want to use `keyCode`, then you can use `event.key`, you will have the same result

Answer (score 0):

You would want to write a function on the (input) event that binds to the textarea element so you can both read from and write to it's value

```
  <textarea #box (input)="catchAndRelease(box)" cols="32" rows="8"></textarea>

  // your map
  transformers = [
    {from: 'a', to: 'z'},
    {from: 'b', to: 'y'},
    {from: 'c', to: 'x'},
    {from: 'd', to: 'w'},
    {from: 'z', to: 'a'}
  ];

  // fires on every (input) event
  catchAndRelease(el: HTMLTextAreaElement) {

      const keyPressed = el.value.split('').pop();
      let transformedKey = keyPressed;

      this.transformers.some(t => {
          if (t.from == keyPressed) {
          transformedKey = t.to;
          return true;
      }
      return false;

  });

  // write the new value back into the <textarea> element
  const newString = el.value.substring(0, el.value.length-1) + transformedKey;
  el.value = newString;
```

}

see it in action: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nkhnec